# Firefox - Arrows disappeared from scrollbar

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk

I recently posted the below question on the firefox website:

I have Firefox 46.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 and a few days ago the arrows of the scrollbar disappeared. I have the scrollbar but the up and down arrows are gone so it is more inconvenient to scroll websites up and down. Can you please confirm how I can fix this issue? Please see the screen shot attached for reference.

I got the following answer:

> You can try to use a different GTK 3 theme in case the theme you
>   currently use isn't working properly with Firefox 46+.
>
> https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/46.0/system-requirements/
>
> Note that Firefox 46.0 and later requires GTK+ 3.4 as a minimum and
>   you need a GTK 3 theme.

So I checked what version of GTK I have and I found the following.

`apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0`:

```
libgtk2.0-0:

 Installed: 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4
 Candidate: 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4
 Version table:
*** 2.24.23-0ubuntu1.4 0
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPackages
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    2.24.23-0ubuntu1 0
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Packages

libgtk-3-0:

 Installed: 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6
 Candidate: 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6
 Version table:
*** 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 0
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    3.10.8-0ubuntu1.4 0
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >Packages>    3.10.8-0ubuntu1 0
       500 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Can somebody please help me and let me know how I change the GTK in Firefox as suggested by Firefox support?

Please note I had to replace the links with xxxxxx in the above terminal output because I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? You can add the URLs to your post -- you have [enough rep](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user) now to post more links, but you can also include non-linkified URLs inside code formatting by indenting four spaces, which is the best way to show most text copied from the Terminal anyway. And you can add the screenshot you mentioned, and link to or otherwise identify the instructions you quoted. If this is solved, then please post an answer with the solution. Otherwise, please [edit] this with all that info, and anything else possibly relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a bit late but maybe someone will use it.

There is an addon for Firefox that changes the scroll bars, called "NewScrollbars (aka NoiaScrollbars)" that may be what your looking for.

The addon changes the new thin scrollbar to a wider one, it also has color settings for the scrollbar.

I can't stand the new interface in Firefox so I have several addon's to get back the old interface this happens to be one of them. Sadly Mozilla is update happy and keeps playing with Firefox in the process loosing much of what brought users to Firefox in the first place

This addin can be found on the Palemoon addins pages it will still work in those using Firefox versions before 57, this also works in the LTS versions of Firefox.    Pale moon addins ["NewScrollbars (aka NoiaScrollbars)"](https://addons.palemoon.org/addon/newscrollbars/) Just download the xpi, then open it in Firefox, and if version compatible it will install.

You will find many of the older addins on the palemoon site, many are just the same as the Firefox version.